# Can I retrieve out from a script run by helm hooks and use that as input for another chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In my gke manifests I have a CRD for reserving a static ip address and a CRD for creating a google dns record- I want to tie these together with helm hooks.

I want to create the gce reserved IP via CRD with one chart and then use helm hooks to run a script that executes gcloud to get the IP that was allocated for that reserved IP (`gcloud compute addresses describe my-ip-name`) and then use that IP as input to create a google dns record.

I want to do this as part of a single helm deployment.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you control those custom resources?  It'd probably be easier to do this in your controller code than to try to wire it together using Helm.

Comment: no this is an operator I do not control

Comment: Can’t you create a Job that creates with a small “kubectl” bash script your second CRD with the value in it?